# MAMP on windows won't run WordPress install

Tags: wordpress, windows, mamp

I am using MAMP on windows 10, and I'm trying to install WordPress but it gives me "`Error establishing a database connection`".
It's connected to MySQL okay, as it shows the box checked in the MAMP UI.

I've tried following:

1. Using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.
2. Adding manual config into the `wp-config.php`.
3. Adding `define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);`.

Why I am getting this error and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many investigations. turned out I was accessing localhost as a host, but while I reset the MAMP ports to default, it uses 8889 and not 8888 or localhost.

Answer (score 0):

In the field of Database Host, use **localhost:8889** instead of only **localhost**.
Here, 8889 is the MySQL port.